# Diseño de una tabla en HTML

Tags: html, datatables

Algo poco comun pero la verdad estoy cero en diseño quisisera saber como hago para que mi tabla tenga esta medida como el de la foto (**QUIERO PONERLO DODNE ESTA EL CUADRO NEGRO**)
Pero nose como hacer el diseño :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CODIGO CON EL QUE GENERO LA TABLA**

```
if (COUNT($reg) != 0) {//VALIDACION
            echo "            <table align='center' >";
            echo "            <thead style='color:white;background:#3C8DBC;'>";
            echo "            <tr>";
            echo "            <th class='alnright' width=10% style='background:#FFF; border: hidden; border-right: 1px solid black;'></th>";
            echo "            <th class='text-center' width=5% style=' color: #000; border: 1px solid black;'><b>N°</b></th>";
            echo "            <th class='text-center' width=20% style=' color: #000; border: 1px solid black;' ><b>PRODUCTO</b></th>";
            echo "            <th class='text-center' width=10% style=' color: #000; border: 1px solid black;' ><b>PRECIO </b></th>";
            echo "            <th class='text-center' width=10% style=' color: #000; border: 1px solid black;' ><b>CANTIDAD</b></th>";
            echo "            <th class='text-center' width=10% style=' color: #000; border: 1px solid black;' ><b>SUBTOTAL</b></th>";
            echo "            </tr>";
            echo "            </thead>";
            echo "            <tbody>";

            $contador = 0;

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($reg); $i++) {
                $contador ++;
                $accesorio = $reg[$i]['nombre'];
                $PRECIO = $reg[$i]['precio'];
                $CANTIDAD = $reg[$i]['cantidad'];
                $SUBTOTAL = $reg[$i]['subtotal'];

                echo "            <tr>";
                echo "            <td style='border: hidden; border-right: 1px solid black;' width='5px'>&nbsp;</td>";
                echo "            <td class='text-center' style='color:white;background:#ECEFF1;; color: #000; border: 1px solid black;'><b>$contador</b></td>";
                echo "            <td class='text-center' style='color:white;background:#ECEFF1; color: #000; border: 1px solid black;'><b>$accesorio</b></td>";
                echo "            <td class='text-center' style='color:white;background:#ECEFF1; color: #000; border: 1px solid black;'><b>$PRECIO</b></td>";
                echo "            <td class='text-center' style='color:white;background:#ECEFF1; color: #000; border: 1px solid black;'><b>$CANTIDAD</b></td>";
                echo "            <td class='text-center' style='color:white;background:#ECEFF1; color: #000; border: 1px solid black;'><b>$SUBTOTAL</b></td>";
                echo "            </tr>";
            }

            echo "            </tbody>";
            echo "            </table>";
        }
```

Comment: El código que compartes no es suficiente para ver el problema (haría falta ver el código de la tabla que contiene a esta tabla). Sería mejor que compartieras el código HTML generado y no el PHP y que crearas un [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que lo mas logico seria

```
echo "  <table width='el tamaño que necesitas'>";
```

o como dicen los compañeros

```
echo "  <table style='width:el tamaño que necesitas;>' ";
```

Saludos.

Comment: agrega style="width : 100%'

Comment: El atributo `width` se ha marcado como obsoleto y su uso no es recomendado. Utiliza `style="width:..."` para indicar el ancho.